# Django Muliple Variables in URL with database update

Tags: django

I'm having some trouble adding an extra variable into my URL. I currently have it setup as:

```
url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/?$', 'blog.views.blog_show', name='show'),
```

However I would like to include the slug in the title too:

```
url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<blog_slug>\S+)/?$', 'blog.views.blog_show', name='show'),
```

I've managed to get this to work however when my users update comments on my blog there is something funny happening as it doesn't record to the database and doesn't redirect properly.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Examples: /blogs
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^new$', 'blog.views.new', name='new'),
    url(r'^create$', 'blog.views.create', name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/?$', 'blog.views.blog_show', name='show'),
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/edit$', 'blog.views.blog_edit', name='edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/update$', 'blog.views.blog_update', name='update'),
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/delete$', 'blog.views.delete_blog', name='delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/new_comment$', 'blog.views.new_comment', name='comment'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

views.py

```
def new_comment(request, blog_id, blog_slug):
    #blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    c = Comment()
    c.comment_content = request.POST['comment_content']
    c.blog_id = blog
    c.user_id = User.objects.all()[0]
    c.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('show', args=(blog.id,)))

def blog_show(request, blog_id, blog_slug):
    #blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    comment_obj = blog.comment_set.all().order_by('-id')

    paginator = Paginator(comment_obj, 2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        comment_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        comment_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        comment_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    template_hash = {'comment_list':comment_list,'blog':blog}
    return render(request, 'blog/show.html',template_hash)
```

show.html

```
{% load django_markdown %}

<h1>{{ blog.blog_title }}</h1>
<p>
    {{ blog.blog_content|markdown}}
</p>
<form action = '/blogs/{{blog.id}}/{{blog.slug}}/new_comment' method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div>New Comment:<br><textarea type = "text" name ='comment_content'></textarea></div>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
<h3>Comments</h3>
{% if comment_list %}
    {% for comment in comment_list %}
        <p>{{comment}}</p>

    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <p>No Comments</p>
{% endif %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if comment_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ comment_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ comment_list.number }} of {{ comment_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if comment_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ comment_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is when I have it redirecting and recording to the database the comments wont record any more and the redirect is stuck at http://localhost:8000/blogs/1/my-first-blog/new_comment. Instead of just going to http://localhost:8000/blogs/1/my-first-blog/

I though by updating the below it would redirect properly but it hasn't

```
 <form action = '/blogs/{{blog.id}}/{{blog.slug}}/new_comment' method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that new URL in context with the other existing ones?

Comment: Yes. Not too worried about the other ones because I can apply the same theory to them when I've got this working. I've tried to update both show and  comment urls to the below:  url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<blog_slug>\S+)/?$', 'blog.views.blog_show', name='show'),
 
    url(r'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<blog_slug>\S+)/new_comment$', 'blog.views.new_comment', name='comment'), But still no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `\S+` matches all string characters, including "/". So the regex `'^(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<blog_slug>\S+)/?$` matches "1/my_blog/new_comment", and your form ends up submitting to the show view rather than the add comment view.

Use `\w+` instead to just match alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Unfortunately when I changed to \w+ i got an error, NoReverseMatch.Reverse for 'show' with arguments '(1, 'my-first-blog')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blogs/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<blog_slug>\\w+)?$']

Comment: Try `[\w-]+` to match hyphens as well as alphanumeric characters.